# How can I bind click function in disabled button using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have button which is by default disabled. I want to show alert message when button is clicked to inform user to do some action in order to enable button.

```
<button type="button" class=" btn btn-success addRow disabled">Add More
                                        </button>

$('.addRow').click(function (e) {
        if ($('.disabled').hasClass('disabled')) {
            e.preventDefault();
            alert('Please select.....');
        }
    });
```

Comment: do you mean to say that, above function is not working? 
are you unable to bind the click event?

Comment: Yes flash. I don't know why it is not working.

Comment: `if($('.disabled').hasClass('disabled'))` makes no sense. It will always return true :o)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Updated:** Check `tbody` show or hide from `:visible` method as `invoice type` selected or not and inside `tbody` also check is selected or not then `addRow` button enable and disabled as conditionally so check below snippet.

```js
/*Select Invoice Type*/
$(document).on('change','#invoiceType', function(){
  if($(this).val()!=''){
    $('#tbody').show();
  }
  else{
    $('#tbody').hide();
    $('.productname').val(''); // Reset value null
    $('#addRow').addClass('disabled'); //addRow button disabled
  }
});

/*Select Product Name*/
$(document).on('change','.productname', function(){
  if($(this).val()!=''){
    $('#addRow').removeClass('disabled');
  }
  else{
    $('#addRow').addClass('disabled');
  }
});

$(document).on('click', '#addRow', function(e){
  if ($('#tbody').is(':visible')) { //Check tbody is visible or not
    if($('.productname').val()!=''){
      // You can add your code here.. for next step which you need...
      $('#tbody').append('<tr><td>'+$('.productname').val()+'</td><td>-</td><td>-</td><td>-</td><td></td></tr>');
      $('.productname').val('') // Reset Product Name Dropdown.
      $('#addRow').addClass('disabled'); // After Product Name listed then addRod button disabled.
    }
    else{
     e.preventDefault();
     alert("Please Select Product Name!");
   }
 }
 else{
   e.preventDefault();
   alert("Please Select Invoice Type!");
  }
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="container-fluid my-3">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3">
      <div class="form-group">
        <select class="custom-select" name="type" id="invoiceType">
          <option value="" selected="selected">Select Invoice Type</option>
          <option value="Flat Discount">Flat Discount</option>
          <option value="Cash Discount">Cash Discount</option>
        </select>
       </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-12">
      <table class="table table-bordered" id="main_table">
        <thead class="bg-light">
          <tr>
            <th scope="col" class="align-middle">PRODUCT NAME</th>
            <th scope="col" class="align-middle">QTY</th>
            <th scope="col" class="align-middle">PRICE</th>
            <th scope="col" class="align-middle">AMOUNT</th>
            <th width="140" class="align-middle"><button type="button" id="addRow" class="btn btn-success disabled">Add More</button></th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody id="tbody" style="display: none;">
          <tr>           
            <td>
              <select name="product_id[]" class="form-control custom-select productname" id="row_0">
                <option value="">Select Product Name</option>
                <option value="Product Name #1">Product Name #1</option>
                <option value="Product Name #2">Product Name #2</option>
                <option value="Product Name #3">Product Name #3</option>
              </select>
            </td>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>-</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>     
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

You can `remove` / `add` class by `removeClass` / `addClass` method so check below snippet.
 I hope this will help you lot.

```js
$(document).on('change','[data-addrow]', function(){
  if($(this).is(':checked')){
    $($(this).attr('data-addrow')).removeClass('disabled');
  }
  else{
    $($(this).attr('data-addrow')).addClass('disabled');
  }
});

$(document).on('click', '.addRow', function (e) {
  if ($('.disabled').hasClass('disabled')) {
    e.preventDefault();
    alert("Please tick checkbox for add more row!");
  }
  else{
    $('.table tbody').append('<tr><td>Raeesh</td><td>Alam</td></tr>')
  }
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="container my-3">
  <div class="row justify-content-center">
    <div class="col-sm-8 col-md-6">
      <div class="form-group">
        <table class="table table-bordered my-3">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>First Name</th>
              <th>Last Name</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
          </tbody>
          <tfoot>
            <tr>
              <td colspan="2">
                <label>
                  <input type="checkbox" name="" data-addrow=".addRow"> Tick for add more row!
                </label>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </tfoot>
        </table>
      </div>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-success addRow disabled">Add More</button>      
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you Raeesh. I have hidden tbody initially. When status from dropdown is selected tbody shows. What I want is when users click on add more initially I want to show alert box to user to select status from dropdown. I have tried using attr, class, prop, but didn't work. Raeesh Alam can you please help me with that.

Comment: Can you add html code into your question description so it will more easy for understanding.

Comment: Ok. What my problem is class="disabled" doesn't disabled the button.

Comment: You want permanently disabled click event if yes then you will need to add **disabled** attribute in button tag

Comment: I don't want permanent disabled button. I have two conditions. First tbody is hidden. When user will click on add more button it will alert to select status. Second when status is selected and tbody appears and again if add more button is clicked it will alert to select product name first. Otherwise button should be disabled. Thank you Raeesh for your help. Any other help will be appreciated.

Comment: Okay, I will add another snippet with status after couple of hour.

Comment: Thank you. I will be waiting for your response.

Comment: I have uploaded another snippet with help of your html structure so check that.

Comment: Thanks Raeesh, this is what i wanted.

Answer (score 0):

You have already selecting disabled element and don't need to check for the same class. Instead, you can perform the action like below:

```
$('.addRow').click(function (e) {
  $(this).toggleClass('disabled');
  // removes if it is disabled or adds if it's not
}
```

See [toggleClass](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass)

And if you want to do something else, you can do exactly like you have done but you just have to use `$(this)` instead of `$('.disabled')` selector.

And if you want to select other element which have disabled class instead of currently clicked element, you can select the element by taking other class like you have `btn`. So, you'll use `$('.btn').hassClass('disabled')`.

Answer (score 0):

Bind your click function in ready state.

```
$(document).ready(function(){    
    $('.addRow').click(function (e) {
        if ($(this).hasClass('disabled')) {
            e.preventDefault();
            alert('Please select.....');
           // Then, after completion of your action, you can remove the disabled class from the below statement
           $(this).removeClass('disabled');
        }
    })
});
```

then you will be able to bind the click event.